# Use of Middleware to manage login/redirect of different user Role to different view in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am beginner to laravel. I am using laravel auth where I add one field of role of user to my user table which I migrate. Then, I register to the application with two roles such as admin and user. but When I log-in then with the help of user details it will automatically check the role of user and load admin view or user view respectively. So, the middleware will call in between the view and controller. How the things happen. Thanks in Advance.

My code :

RegisterController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
        {
            return Validator::make($data, [
            .....   
            'role' => 'required|min:4|',
        ]);
}
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
      ....
    'role' => $data['role'],
 ]);
}
```

AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

AdminMiddleware.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()->role != 'admin')
        {
            return redirect('home');
        }
        if ($request->user()->role != 'user')
        {
            return redirect('user');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware'], function()
{
    Route::get('/home', function()
    {
         return view('home');
    });

});
```

kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
            ....
           'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
         ];
```

Comment: Do you get redirected to login page when you go to this route? what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am not able to get the role of user and according to that role my page should route to specific page if user is admin or a normal user.

Comment: can anyone help me through out the whole code as this code doesn't work for me.